# Angular 2 way of changing an element's data attribute

Tags: angular

I am working with ConvertFlow, which adds previously created form templates, where you tell it do add this; you do this by adding a div containing the id of the form you created on their system. This part is not the issue, except that the form HTML is being created by this service, so I don't have access to it, to add ids, etc.

There is an element in the form, which I would like to hide, and this element has a data attribute called `data-visible`. In plain js, I can accomplish this with:

`$('div[data-field="policyNumber"]').attr("data-visible", false);`

However, I am not sure what the Angular way would be. I thought `ChildView` could help, but there are no ids on these elements for me to access, so is there another better way? Perhaps something using `querySelector`?

`(<any>document).querySelector('div[data-field="policyNumber"]')`

I thought this might work too, but how do you access and change the data attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is using `ElementRef` and `Renderer2`.

In your component, inject both dependencies

```
constructor(
    private _elRef: ElementRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

And where ever you want to update the attribute

```
const el = (this._elRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector('[data-field="policyNumber"]');

this._renderer.setAttribute(el, 'data-visible', 'false');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use document.querySelector, you can inject e.g. `ElementRef` and search through it's `elRef.nativeElement.querySelector` method. E.g.

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private div: any;

  constructor(private elRef: elementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.div = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div[data-field="policy-number"]');
  }
```

As for setting values to data attributes, it's relatively simple with Renderer2. From the above example onwards:

```
class Mycomponent {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  private setAttribute() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div'), 'data-field', 'policy-number');
  }
}
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-attribute?file=src/app/app.component.ts) an example stackblitz.